# How to remove the end of the x-axis in d3.js

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B1Cz.png)

I am creating a d3.js chart in react.js.
And I want to remove the end of the x-axis as shown.

How do I remove that part?

```
useEffect(() => {
const svg = select(svgRef.current);

const colorScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain([55, 100, 200])
    .range(["green", "orange", "red"])
    .clamp(true)

// create x-axis
const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale).ticks(data.length);
svg.select(".x-axis").style("transform", "translateY(300px").call(xAxis);

// create y-axis
const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale);
svg.select(".y-axis").style("transform", "translateX(0px").call(yAxis);

//svg.selectAll("path").attr("stroke", "#ddd") 
svg.select(".y-axis").select("path").attr("stroke", "transparent") 
svg.select(".x-axis").select("path").attr("fill", "none").attr("stroke-width", "1px").attr("stroke", "#888") // y축 path만 선택
svg.selectAll("line").attr("stroke", "#ddd")
```

...

Comment: You should make it so we can easily run the code you want exaimed like shown in this unrelated question about d3.js... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430884/using-d3-to-animate-a-virtual-wheel-how-to-make-it-spin-realistically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting outerTickSize and innerTickSize to 0:

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 25])
    .range([0, width]);
 
var data = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21];

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("top")
    .tickValues(data)
    .innerTickSize(0)
    .outerTickSize(0);
 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
 
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100" height="100"></svg>
```

[Reference](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/6579467)